# Get MAX row for GROUP in MySQL

Tags: mysql, group-by, greatest-n-per-group

I have the following data:

```
+---------+----------+----------+--------+
|      id | someId   | number   | data   |
+---------+----------+----------+--------+
|      27 |      123 |        1 | abcde1 |
|      28 |      123 |        3 | abcde2 |
|      29 |      123 |        1 | abcde3 |
|      30 |      123 |        5 | abcde4 |
|      31 |      124 |        4 | abcde1 |
|      32 |      124 |        8 | abcde2 |
|      33 |      124 |        1 | abcde3 |
|      34 |      124 |        2 | abcde4 |
|      35 |      123 |       16 | abcde1 |
|     245 |      123 |        3 | abcde2 |
|     250 |      125 |        0 | abcde3 |
|     251 |      125 |        1 | abcde4 |
|     252 |      125 |        7 | abcde1 |
|     264 |      125 |        0 | abcde2 |
|     294 |      123 |        0 | abcde3 |
|     295 |      126 |        0 | abcde4 |
|     296 |      126 |        0 | abcde1 |
|     376 |      126 |        0 | abcde2 |
+---------+----------+----------+--------+
```

And I want to get a MySQL query that gets me the **data** of the row with the highest **number** for each **someId**. Note that **id** is unique, but **number** isn't

Comment: What did you want to happen where you have a tie on the max number for the someId?

Comment: in that case, take one of them arbitrarily (or whatever other behavior you can get me ;-) )

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Retrieving the last record in each group - MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313120/retrieving-the-last-record-in-each-group-mysql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slight tweak to Naeel's answer but to return just a single data result for any someId even if there's a tie you should add a `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT t1.someid, t1.number, t1.data
FROM Table1 t1
INNER JOIN (SELECT someId sid, max(number) max_number 
            FROM Table1
            GROUP BY someId) t2 
ON (someId = sid AND number = max_number)
GROUP BY t1.someId
```

SQL Fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ac249/13)

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT someid, highest_number, data
FROM test_1
  INNER JOIN (SELECT someid sid, max(number) highest_number 
              FROM test_1
              GROUP BY someid) t 
  ON (someid=sid and number=highest_number)
```

Unfortunately it is not look quite efficient. In Oracle it could be possible to user OVER clause without subqueries, but MySQL…

**Update 1**

If there are several instances of highest **number** this will returs also several **data** for each pair of **someid** and **number**. 
To get the only row per each **someid** we should preaggregate the source table to make **someid** and **number** pairs unique (see t1 subquery)

```
SELECT someid, highest_number, data
FROM 
  (SELECT someid, number, MIN(data) data
   FROM test_1
   GROUP BY
   someid, number) t1
INNER JOIN 
  (SELECT someid sid, max(number) highest_number 
   FROM test_1
   GROUP BY someid) t2
ON (someid=sid and number=highest_number)
```

**Update 2**

It is possible to simplify previous solution

```
SELECT someid,highest_nuimber,
  (select min(data)
   from test_1 
   where someid=t1.someid and number=highest_nuimber)
FROM
   (SELECT someid, max(number) highest_nuimber
    FROM test_1
    GROUP BY someid) t1
```

If we materialize unique pairs of **someid** and **number** than it is possible to use correlated subquery. Unlike a JOIN it would not produce additional rows if highest value of **number** is repeated several times.

Comment: Well, I guess if there's an index on number it should be fine... But how do I get just one per every **someId**?

Comment: This should return one for every someId except for when you have a tie.

Comment: And once again: the last variant uses corelated subquery instead of JOIN