# Postgresql get max row group by column

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

I am trying to get the max row from the sum of daily counts in a table.  I have looked at several posts that look similar, however it doesn't seem to work.  I have tried to follow
[Get MAX row for GROUP in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23385748/get-max-row-for-group-in-mysql)
but it doesn't work in Postgres.  Here's what I have

```
select source, SUM(steps) as daily_steps, to_char("endTime"::date, 'MM/DD/YYYY') as step_date
 from activities
 where user_id = 1
 and "endTime" <= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL '1 day'
 and "endTime" >= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL '7 days' 
 group by source, to_char("endTime"::date, 'MM/DD/YYYY')
```

This returns the following

```
source, daily_steps, step_date
"walking";750;"11/17/2015"
"walking";821;"11/22/2015"
"walking";106;"11/20/2015"
"running";234;"11/21/2015"
"running";600;"11/24/2015"
```

I would like the result to return only the rows that have the max value for daily_steps by source.  The result should look like

```
source, daily_steps, step_date
"walking";821;"11/22/2015"
"running";600;"11/24/2015"
```

Comment: `group by source, to_char("endTime"::date, 'MM/DD/YYYY')` You seem to come from another planet. What is wrong with `endTime::date`) ??

Comment: I need the format of date to be specific for the user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Postgres offers the convenient `distinct on` syntax:

```
select distinct on (a.source) a.*
from (select source, SUM(steps) as daily_steps, to_char("endTime"::date, 'MM/DD/YYYY') as step_date
      from activities a
      where user_id = 1 and
            "endTime" <= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL '1 day' and
            "endTime" >= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL '7 days' 
      group by source, to_char("endTime"::date, 'MM/DD/YYYY')
     ) a
order by a.source, daily_steps desc;
```